# Poner imágenes personalizadas por rango en la barra input rango

Tags: html, css, input

Quisiera poner imágenes que cambien dependiendo el rango del input
El código que agrego no es mío, me ayudaron aquí pero no se donde mover

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("vol");
var output = document.getElementById("outvol");
let estado = 'estado medio';

output.innerHTML = estado;

slider.oninput = function() {
  correlacion_valores = {
    '0': 'sin estado',
    '0.1': 'mal estado',
    '0.2': 'estado bajo',
    '0.3': 'estado no tan bajo',
    '0.4': 'estado menos bajo',
    '0.5': 'estado medio',
    '0.6': 'estado medio y subiendo',
    '0.7': 'estado notable bajo',
    '0.8': 'estado notable alto',
    '0.9': 'estado superior',
    '1': 'estado máximo'
  }

  estado = correlacion_valores[this.value];
  output.innerHTML = estado;
};
```

```html
<p><label for="vol">Nivel de Sanidad:</label>
<input style="width:80%;" type="range" id="vol" name="vol" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5"><br>
<output id="outvol" name="outvol" for="vol">Estado medio</output>
</p>
```

Las imágenes serian por rango, espero puedan apoyarme y los resultados sean de apoyo para otros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo de las imágenes lo tienes facil, tan solo debes seguir la misma lógica que con el rango, de este modo:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("vol");
var output = document.getElementById("outvol");
var outputimagen = document.getElementById("imagen");
let estado = 'estado medio';

output.innerHTML = estado;

slider.oninput = function() {
  correlacion_valores = {
    '0': 'sin estado',
    '0.1': 'mal estado',
    '0.2': 'estado bajo',
    '0.3': 'estado no tan bajo',
    '0.4': 'estado menos bajo',
    '0.5': 'estado medio',
    '0.6': 'estado medio y subiendo',
    '0.7': 'estado notable bajo',
    '0.8': 'estado notable alto',
    '0.9': 'estado superior',
    '1': 'estado máximo'
  }

  correlacion_imagenes = {
    '0': 'https://pngimg.com/uploads/smiley/small/smiley_PNG36233.png',
    '0.1': 'https://pngimg.com/uploads/smiley/small/smiley_PNG36229.png',
    '0.2': 'https://pngimg.com/uploads/smiley/small/smiley_PNG36228.png',
    '0.3': 'https://pngimg.com/uploads/smiley/small/smiley_PNG198.png',
    '0.4': 'https://pngimg.com/uploads/smiley/small/smiley_PNG188.png',
    '0.5': 'https://pngimg.com/uploads/smiley/small/smiley_PNG179.png',
    '0.6': 'https://pngimg.com/uploads/smiley/small/smiley_PNG170.png',
    '0.7': 'https://pngimg.com/uploads/smiley/small/smiley_PNG138.png',
    '0.8': 'https://pngimg.com/uploads/smiley/small/smiley_PNG124.png',
    '0.9': 'https://pngimg.com/uploads/smiley/small/smiley_PNG77.png',
    '1': 'https://pngimg.com/uploads/smiley/small/smiley_PNG135.png'
  }

  estado = correlacion_valores[this.value];
  imagen = correlacion_imagenes[this.value];
  output.innerHTML = estado;
  outputimagen.setAttribute("src", imagen)
  
};
```

```html
<p><label for="vol">Nivel de Sanidad:</label>
<input style="width:80%;" type="range" id="vol" name="vol" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5"><br>
<output id="outvol" name="outvol" for="vol">Estado medio</output>
<img id="imagen" src="" width="200px">
</p>
```

En cuanto a lo del color gradiente y marcas de rango, yo haria una nueva pregunta, pues las preguntas deben ser únicas para que las respuestas tambien lo sean y puedan ayudar a más gente. Y cuando lo hagas pon lo que has intentado, porque así veremos en que has fallado, pues a mi no se me ocurre como hacerlo, pero si tu dices que algo habias conseguido quizás pueda ayudarte si veo tu código.

Comment: Si gracias y gracias por la ayuda para hacer lo de los rangos

Comment: ya agregue el código que use para el gradiente

Comment: Te decia que hicieras una nueva pregunta, no que ampliaras esta, pues uno de los motivos de cierre de preguntas es hacer varias a la vez, y es lo que estas pidiendo en esta: 1) Imaǵenes y 2) Background y marcas de rango.  Haz una nueva pregunta con mi nuevo código, más el tuyo, y con un HTML que funcione para lo del background, pues con el que hay ahora no funciona y no se el porque (quizas le falta algo de CSS tambien para que funcione).  Cuando lo tengas me avisas con el enlace y lo miro, y de paso edita esta pregunta preguntando solo lo de las imagenes para que la respuesta sea buena.

Comment: Ya cree la otra publicación  [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/536539/modificar-background-de-input-range-con-tickmarks) muchas gracias @masterguru