# Modificar background de input range con tickmarks

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

Quisiera me apoyaran a modificar los estilos de mi input range.
Use unos ejemplos que encontré pero quiero asignarlos con un ID porque quisiera agregar mas input range y todos tienen el mismo formato. también quisiera agregar "tickmarks" con su label pero por los estilos no aparecen

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("vol");
var output = document.getElementById("outvol");
var outputimagen = document.getElementById("imagen");
let estado = 'Escala Análisis de Sanidad Vegetal';

output.innerHTML = estado;

slider.oninput = function() {
  correlacion_valores = {
    '0': 'Suelo desnudo',
    '0.1': 'Vegetación muerta',
    '0.2': 'Estrés hídrico',
    '0.3': 'Daños por presencia de plagas y/o enfermedades',
    '0.4': 'Deficiencia fuerte de nutrientes',
    '0.5': 'Presencia de plagas y/o enfermedades',
    '0.6': 'Deficiencia nutrientes',
    '0.7': 'Buena condición de producción',
    '0.8': 'Excelente condición de producción',
    '0.9': 'Excelente condición de producción',
  }

  correlacion_imagenes = {
    '0': 'https://previews.123rf.com/images/oocoskun/oocoskun1610/oocoskun161000016/65788157-antecedentes-de-suelo-desnudo-con-copia-espacio-para-los-conceptos-sobre-la-jardiner%C3%ADa-la-horticultu.jpg',
    '0.1': 'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/corn-crop-or-withered-crop-due-to-climate-change-picture-id1175270373?s=2048x2048',
    '0.2': 'https://www.eldiariodelcentrodelpais.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/p18-f1-rural.jpg',
    '0.3': 'https://www.gob.mx/cms/uploads/image/file/640818/plaga1.jpg',
    '0.4': 'https://www.dekalb.es/documents/89430/235900/05.jpg/5c235181-bb6a-4a35-a119-00ce2af11141?t=1423645241000',
    '0.5': 'https://www.gob.mx/cms/uploads/image/file/640819/Puccinia-sorgui.jpg',
    '0.6': 'https://www.dekalb.es/documents/89430/235900/06.jpg/947424ac-bae0-4aca-9166-b83308c7f8ae?t=1423645241000',
    '0.7': 'https://agrotendencia.tv/agropedia/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/maiz1.jpg',
    '0.8': 'https://www.intagri.com/assets/images/articulos/categoria1/9Cereales/art202-alto-rendimiento-en-maiz/proporcion.jpg',
    '0.9': 'https://webcdn.agroptima.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/20121440/cultivo-maiz1.jpg',
  }

  estado = correlacion_valores[this.value];
  imagen = correlacion_imagenes[this.value];
  output.innerHTML = estado;
  outputimagen.setAttribute("src", imagen)
  
};
```

```css
input[type=range] {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 70%;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        background: rgb(215, 0, 3);
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(215, 0, 3, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 122, 0, 1) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(29, 221, 0, 1) 75%, rgba(0, 115, 186, 1) 100%);

        border-radius: 10px;
        /* Esta configuración de propiedad hace que los gráficos al llenar la barra de progreso se redondeen */
    }

    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }

    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        /* Establecer la pista en esquinas redondeadas */
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #def3f8, inset 0 .125em .125em #0d1112;
        /* Seguimiento del efecto de sombra incorporado */
    }

    input[type=range]:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        margin-top: -5px;
        /* Iguala el desplazamiento del control deslizante más allá de la pista */
        background: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        /* La apariencia se establece en redonda */
        border: solid 0.125em rgba(205, 224, 230, 0.5);
        /* Establecer borde */
        box-shadow: 0 .125em .125em #3b4547;
        /* Agregar sombra inferior */
    }
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="mx-auto">
            <div class="text-center fw-bold" style="height:100px ;">
                <output id="outvol" name="outvol" for="vol"></output>
                <p><img id="imagen" src="" height="70px"></p>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="text-center fw-bold"><label for="vol">Nivel de Sanidad:</label>
                <input type="range" id="vol" name="vol" min="0" max="0.9" step="0.1" value="0.4">
            </div>
```

Se los gradeceré mucho y espero que les sirva a más personas con el mismo problema. gracias por su apoyo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se pudiera algo asi o ya aunque sea solo las marcas con su label

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intente agregar las marcas pero solo me funciono quitando todo así como en los ejemplos de
[aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como bien dice la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range) no esta implementado todo, pero con un poco de tiempo e ingenio se logra.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("vol");
var output = document.getElementById("outvol");
var outputimagen = document.getElementById("imagen");
let estado = 'Escala Análisis de Sanidad Vegetal';
var  correlacion_valores = {
    '0': 'Suelo desnudo',
    '0.1': 'Vegetación muerta',
    '0.2': 'Estrés hídrico',
    '0.3': 'Daños por presencia de plagas y/o enfermedades',
    '0.4': 'Deficiencia fuerte de nutrientes',
    '0.5': 'Presencia de plagas y/o enfermedades',
    '0.6': 'Deficiencia nutrientes',
    '0.7': 'Buena condición de producción',
    '0.8': 'Excelente condición de producción',
    '0.9': 'Excelente condición de producción',
  }
var correlacion_imagenes = {
    '0': 'https://previews.123rf.com/images/oocoskun/oocoskun1610/oocoskun161000016/65788157-antecedentes-de-suelo-desnudo-con-copia-espacio-para-los-conceptos-sobre-la-jardiner%C3%ADa-la-horticultu.jpg',
    '0.1': 'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/corn-crop-or-withered-crop-due-to-climate-change-picture-id1175270373?s=2048x2048',
    '0.2': 'https://www.eldiariodelcentrodelpais.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/p18-f1-rural.jpg',
    '0.3': 'https://www.gob.mx/cms/uploads/image/file/640818/plaga1.jpg',
    '0.4': 'https://www.dekalb.es/documents/89430/235900/05.jpg/5c235181-bb6a-4a35-a119-00ce2af11141?t=1423645241000',
    '0.5': 'https://www.gob.mx/cms/uploads/image/file/640819/Puccinia-sorgui.jpg',
    '0.6': 'https://www.dekalb.es/documents/89430/235900/06.jpg/947424ac-bae0-4aca-9166-b83308c7f8ae?t=1423645241000',
    '0.7': 'https://agrotendencia.tv/agropedia/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/maiz1.jpg',
    '0.8': 'https://www.intagri.com/assets/images/articulos/categoria1/9Cereales/art202-alto-rendimiento-en-maiz/proporcion.jpg',
    '0.9': 'https://webcdn.agroptima.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/20121440/cultivo-maiz1.jpg',
  }

output.innerHTML = estado;

slider.oninput = function() {
 
  estado = correlacion_valores[this.value];
  imagen = correlacion_imagenes[this.value];
  output.innerHTML = estado;
  outputimagen.setAttribute("src", imagen);
  slider.title=this.value;
};

function genera_divs(id){
  let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  let lista=Object.keys(correlacion_valores);
  let espacio_unitario=slider.offsetWidth/lista.length
  newDiv.className = "div_padre";
  newDiv.style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat("+lista.length+", 1fr)";
  for (var i=0; i<lista.length; i++){
    let nuevoDiv=document.createElement("div");
   let nuevoValor=document.createTextNode(i);
    nuevoDiv.appendChild(nuevoValor);
    newDiv.appendChild(nuevoDiv);
  }
  newDiv.style.width = (slider.offsetWidth+espacio_unitario)+"px";
  newDiv.style.left = slider.offsetLeft+"px";
  let slid=document.getElementById(id);
  slid.parentNode.appendChild(newDiv);
}
genera_divs('vol');
genera_divs('vol2');
genera_divs('vol3');
genera_divs('vol4');
```

```css
input[type=range] {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 70%;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        background: rgb(215, 0, 3);
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(215, 0, 3, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 122, 0, 1) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(29, 221, 0, 1) 75%, rgba(0, 115, 186, 1) 100%);

        border-radius: 10px;
        /* Esta configuración de propiedad hace que los gráficos al llenar la barra de progreso se redondeen */
    }

    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }

    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        /* Establecer la pista en esquinas redondeadas */
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #def3f8, inset 0 .125em .125em #0d1112;
        /* Seguimiento del efecto de sombra incorporado */
    }

    input[type=range]:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        margin-top: -5px;
        /* Iguala el desplazamiento del control deslizante más allá de la pista */
        background: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        /* La apariencia se establece en redonda */
        border: solid 0.125em rgba(205, 224, 230, 0.5);
        /* Establecer borde */
        box-shadow: 0 .125em .125em #3b4547;
        /* Agregar sombra inferior */
    }
  .div_padre{
  display: grid;
  position: absolute;
}   
.div_padre div{
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 10px;
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #111111;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.boxd{
  height:60px;
}
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="mx-auto">
            <div class="text-center fw-bold" style="height:100px ;">
                <output id="outvol" name="outvol" for="vol"></output>
                <p><img id="imagen" src="" height="70px"></p>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="text-center fw-bold boxd"><label for="vol">Nivel de Sanidad:</label>
                <input type="range" id="vol" name="vol" min="0" max="0.9" step="0.1" value="0.4">
            </div>
        <div class="text-center fw-bold boxd"><label for="vol">Nivel de Sanidad:</label>
                <input type="range" id="vol2" name="vol" min="0" max="0.9" step="0.1" value="0.4">
            </div>
        <div class="text-center fw-bold boxd"><label for="vol">Nivel de Sanidad:</label>
                <input type="range" id="vol3" name="vol" min="0" max="0.9" step="0.1" value="0.4">
            </div>
        <div class="text-center fw-bold boxd"><label for="vol">Nivel de Sanidad:</label>
                <input type="range" id="vol4" name="vol" min="0" max="0.9" step="0.1" value="0.4">
            </div>
```

Comment: Por cierto y si quiero hacerlo para 5 clases? ya lo intente pero me marca solo los numeros del centro del 1 al 4  si quito las otras del ejemplo

Comment: revisa la respuesta de nuevo, allí puedes ver mas ejemplos

Comment: Si, ya incluso lo pegue tal cual y todo se mueve al centro en una regla pequeña con todos los datos